# how to create different binary version for project using maven?

Tags: maven

I have one project which has a dependency. And this dependency has different versions, and I'd like to release my project with different versions of this dependency as a whole tar bar. Do I need to do the different version release separately (currently I use maven-assembly-plugin for one release). or there's any maven plugin that I can use ?

Comment: You mean you would like to have different tar bar files, one per each different dependency version (which I suppose), or a whole tar bar file with all the different versions of the dependency in it?

Comment: different tar bar for different dependency version

Comment: I updated my answer providing further details, hope that helps.

Answer (score 0):

Several solutions are possible in my opinion, described below (last one suggested):

### **Using a property**

You can use a property as placeholder of the dependency version and change it dinamically via command line as part of the build and as such change every time the version applied to the new artefact.
Hence, in your pom you could define the property as following:

```
<properties>
   ...
   <dependencyname.version>1.2</dependencyname.version>
</properties>
```

Where `dependencyname` is the name of the concerned dependency.
Then, in the dependencies section you could apply the placeholder as following:

```
<dependencies>
   ...
   <dependency>
      <groupId>the-group-id</groupId>
      <artifactId>the-artifact-id</artifactId>
      <version>${dependencyname.version}</version>
   </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

Then, from command line you can override this value anytime simply passing it via the artifactId `-D` option (name=value)

i.e. `mvn clean install -Ddependencyname.version=1.2`

**Advantage**: you have a centralize point for changing the version at runtime or hardcoded as part of your build.
**Disavantage**: you need a build for each version, you need to manually change the version each time.

### **Using profiles**

You can use profiles, a profile per each dependency version. Then activate the profile at runtime (using a default one for the version you are currently using or you prefer) and use the associated version to generate the associated artifact.
Hence, in your code you could for instance define a profile as following:

```
<profiles>
...
   <profile>
        <id>dependency-name-v1.2</id>
        <dependencies>
           ...
           <dependency>
              <groupId>the-group-id</groupId>
              <artifactId>the-artifact-id</artifactId>
              <version>1.2</version>
           </dependency>
        </dependencies>
   </profile>
   <profile>
        <id>dependency-name-v1.3</id>
        <dependencies>
           ...
           <dependency>
              <groupId>the-group-id</groupId>
              <artifactId>the-artifact-id</artifactId>
              <version>1.3</version>
           </dependency>
        </dependencies>
   </profile>
</profiles>
```

Once the profile is activated, it will override the version of the concerned dependency at runtime. Any time you can switch it on/off via command line as following:

i.e. `mvn clean install -Pdependency-name-v1.2`

**Advantage**: the required versions are clearly defined in profiles.
**Disavantage**: you need a build for each version, you need to manually change the profile name at runtime based on the desired version to use.

### **Using modules**

As Maven best practices, one project should have only one artefact. Hence, you could have a [multimodule](https://maven.apache.org/pom.html#Aggregation) project and a module per different version and have all the versions/artefacts generated at once as part of your parent/aggregator build. As such, you would also not need any manual intervention as for the cases above (changing property value at runtime or activate a certain profile).
A parent/aggregator project can look as following:

```
...
<packaging>pom</packaging>
...
<modules>
   <module>project-name-v1.2</module>
   <module>project-name-v1.3</module>
</modules>
...
```

Where each module is a subfolder providing yet another Maven project. In each  module you define clearly the dependency and the required version. When building the parent, you would in cascade build all the modules and get all the required artefacts at once.

i.e. `mvn clean install` or `mvn clean install -pl module-1.2version` to build only one module/version required

**Advantage**: No need for manual interventions, separation of concerns, maintainability.
**Disavantage**: A bit more complex build (depending on habits), review of the existing design/structure of the project.